# How do I change the tab colour in IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-9

My desktop is black in colour and my taskbar settings etc. are black...had these same settings the whole time I was using IE 8 but in IE 9 I can't clearly read the text on a tab!  Annoying!  Is there any way to make the text(webpage title) on a tab more clear without altering my desktop and taskbar colour?  Sometimes the tabs are much clearer in grey but other times they are black...

Is there maybe an add-on/3rd party plug-in to solve this problem?

Win 7 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

[Disabling Colored Tabs](http://www.trishtech.com/internet/disable_colored_tabs_in_internet_explorer_9.php) might help :

- From the `Gear` button in the Command Bar select `Internet Options`.
- Select the `Settings` button under Tabs.
- Uncheck `Enable Tab Groups`.
- `OK` twice.
- Restart IE.

If your problem is the transparency of the tabs, then unfortunately the only way to get rid
of it is to turn off transparency in Aero, meaning everywhere on the desktop.

One does that by : Right-click on a blank spot on the Desktop => Personalize. At the bottom of the page, click, "Window color" and uncheck "Enable transparency".

One can also use the Color intensity slider for how transparent you want it.

Comment: What IS coloured tabs?  The purpose...?

Comment: For what : see [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/enhanced-tabs). The purpose: commercial eye-candy.

Comment: The colour is useful but I guess I can't have this feature which sometimes blackens tabs?

Comment: Oops, I meant can't have this feature if I want to avoid the unreadeable tabs?

Comment: I wouldn't know, since I don't use a black theme. This was only a possibility I thought of : that black conflicts with color tabs. But it's easy enough for you to try (and undo if it doesn't help).

Comment: But that's the thing the colours on the tabs are fine like orange, green etc. but why some tabs are black I don't get.

Comment: Does disabling Colored Tabs improve the readability ?

Comment: Nope.  It seems like the issue is the transparency of the tabs; other pages or windows that are open behind it peek through...

Comment: I have added a way to disable that transparency totally or partially.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, more of a suggestion. I too have a custom colour desktop theme and when it comes to the browser, i would definitely recommend chrome as a solid choice. Not only is it a great browser but its customisation options are excellent, there are hundreds of custom themes that are easily attained.

Personally, i love the transparency effects so in reality it has no colour, it takes on the look of the desktop which produces a nice effect.

If your open to switching browsers then try chrome, you can even import all your IE favourites and what not too.

Comment: I already have Chrome but I don't like it as my main tool.